# List.filter function not working in SML/NJ

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

I'm building a simple function to remove `item` from `List1` ...

```
fun Strip(item, List1) = filter (fn x => x <> item) List1;
```

Input:

```
Strip(3,[1,2,3,4,3]);
```

Error:

```
Error: Unbound variable or constructor: Strip
```

Alternate input:

```
filter (fn x => x <> 5) [1,3,5,2,5];
```

Alternate error:

```
stdIn:1.2-1.8 Error: unbound variable or constructor: filter
```

Any ideas why such a simple function isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the error message "unbound variable or constructor: filter", in this case it means that the identifier "filter" is not present in the toplevel environment. Since `filter` is defined in the structure `List`, you'll have to either use `List.filter`, or issue the statement `open List` before using `filter`. For example,

```
List.filter (fn x => x <> 5) [1,3,5,2,5];
```

or

```
open List;
filter (fn x => x <> 5) [1,3,5,2,5];
```

As for the error when using `Strip`, are you certain that your definition of `Strip` was successful and there were no errors? If you tried using `filter` like your code shows, and the interpreter couldn't find it, the definition of `Strip` should have failed.

Comment: I took your advice and tried `open List` as well as simply using `List.filter` but neither worked.

`List.filter (fn x => x <> 5) [1,2,3,4,5];`

Yields this output: 
    `[autoloading]`
    `unexpected exception (bug?) in SML/NJ: Io [Io: openIn failed on`
`"C:\cygwin\home\larsberg\smlnj2\sml.boot.x86`
`-win32\smlnj\basis\.cm\x86-win32\basis.cm", win32-bin-prim`
`-io:checkHndl: openRd: failed]`

    `raised at: Basis/Implementation/IO/bin-io-fn.sml:617.25-617.71`
             `../cm/util/safeio.sml:30.11`
             `../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55`

Comment: Fixed it by creating the folder C:\cygwin\home\larsberg\smlnj2\sml.boot.x86-win34 and copying the basis files into it.