# SML/NJ Basis Library not working in Windows 10

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am using the most recent version of SMLNJ (110.79) on Windows 10.

I cannot seem to use any of the SML Basis Library functions.

Here is an example I tried with `List.filter`

```
fun isOdd nmbr = (nmbr mod 2) = 1;
List.filter isOdd [1,2,3,4,5];
```

This produces the following error

> unexpected exception (bug?) in SML/NJ: Io [Io: openIn failed on "C:\cygwin\home\larsberg\smlnj2\sml.boot.x86-win32\smlnj\basis.cm\x86-win32\basis.cm", win32-bin-prim-io:checkHndl: openRd: failed]
>     raised at: Basis/Implementation/IO/bin-io-fn.sml:617.25-617.71
>                ../cm/util/safeio.sml:30.11
>                ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55

Other functions in the Basis library produce the same error, such as `Real.fromInt`

The comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21874881/2278598) point to a similar problem, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Am I missing something simple? Thanks!

EDIT:

After uninstalling and reinstalling several times, it *seems* to be working. I'll leave this question open for now since I don't really know what got it to actually work..

`List.filter;` gave this output

```
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/(basis.cm):basis-common.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val it = fn : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

Comment: Your question should really be about SML/NJ not working properly on Windows. It has very little to do with List.filter in particular, as you say yourself.

Comment: You're right, I reworded the question a bit

Comment: Maybe you could try to use Windows installer directly rather than going through Cygwin (if that wouldn't cause too much difficulty with your code base). It could be more of a Cygwin vs. Windows 10 problem rather than an SML/NJ vs. Windows 10 problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I did though. I just got the `.msi` directly from here http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.79/index.html

Comment: I based my comment on seeing Cygwin in the error message you gave. I used the windows installer (on Windows 7, not 10) for 110.79 and had no problem -- but nothing is installed on a Cygwin directory (I don't even have Cygwin on my machine). I wonder if the installer does something differently if it detects Cygwin. If you chose that directory -- maybe uninstall then reinstall using the default directory that the installer suggests. If worse comes to worse, you could try to compile from source following these instructions: http://smlnj.org/dist/working/110.79/WININSTALL

Comment: Hm. I don't have Cygwin installed on my machine either. I just tried reinstalling SML/NJ and it defaults to "C:\Program Files (x86)\SMLNJ\"

Comment: Nevermind -- I latched onto "C:\Cygwin\..." but on closer examination it seems that the error message is referring to a file on the machine of the person who packaged the installer rather than on your machine (unless your name is "larsberg"), which seems a bit odd. Glad you finally got it working. It probably couldn't hurt to keep the question in case other people have trouble installing on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the installed directory is moved or the SMLNJ home environment is not set. Basically sml is unable to find the basis.cm file, which should be present in $SMLNJ_HOME sub-directory. Thus by setting the install path in **$SMLNJ_HOME** solved the problem for me.

```
  $SMLNJ_HOME=~/ws/CSCI-5161/sml
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 7 but got the same error. The windows installer put the program in Program Files(x86)/SMLNJ. I moved SMLNJ folder to Program Files/ and now am no longer getting the error.